# Cant debug `iostream` related code when using MSVC toolchain in clion

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, clion

I am new to c++ development, and I find that I can't place breakpoints in iostream related class and if I force step into call of iostream functions  like `basic_streambuf::xsgetn` I will get a disassembly view which I have absolutely no interest to read.

I am using clion with `Visual Studio` Toolchain. Is there a way to debug normally with those classes?

By the way, how to use lldb to get actual value of `unique_ptr`， now I am using `ptr._Mypair._Myval2` which seems really ugly....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of digging. It turns out that adding the following to CMakeLists.txt fixed the problem

```
if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "MSVC")
    message(STATUS " MSVC DEBUG RUNTIME")
    # enable debugging of runtime library
    set_property(TARGET archive_patcher_cpp PROPERTY
            MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreadedDebug")
endif()
```

**Note: this will link runtime statically so the executable size will be a lot bigger**, and this requires cmake 3.15 or higher.

reference: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/prop_tgt/MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html

#### For cmake lower than 3.15:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")
```